# Use native resolution in DrawingArea on HiDPI displays

Tags: macos, gtk, retina-display, gtkmm, retina

I'm developing a cross-platform photo retouching application based on Gtk-2 (but already able to support Gtk-3 with minor modifications).

In my program, the result of the image retouching is previewed in a scrollable area that is implemented through a Gtk::DrawingArea inserted into a Gtk::ScrolledWindow. The drawing itself is performed using Cairo.

Recently I had the possibility to test the software on a MacBookPro laptop with retina display, and I've immediately realised that the preview image gets magnified by a factor of 2, like all the rest of the GUI elements.

Is there a way to tell Cairo and the DrawingArea to use the native screen resolution, instead of applying a 2x magnification? Is this supported in recent Gtk-3 versions?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, recent versions of GTK+ 3 support high DPI. I'm not sure how it works, though.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, what I probably need to figure out is if the 2x magnification can be enabled/disabled on a per-widget basis. Up to now I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: This change in cairo 1.14.0 is probably relevant: "Improve handling of device transformation and scaling, allowing Cairo to now support scaling at a device level, permitting easier, more transparent HiDPI support." Still I need to figure out how this should be applied to a DrawingArea, so that rendering an image into the DrawingArea would use the native resolution of the display, while all the rest of the GUI is up-scaled by a factor of 2.

Comment: Is there a concrete example somewhere,  or some more information on how to achieve what the OP was asking?